Gnome uninstallable, KDE uninstallable, cannot login anymore
I am  a Linux newbie. I recently upgraded to KDE 6. However, after that everything went wrong. My audio stopped working, and I tried recovering it following the suggestions of this website here. But this did not solve my problem. I then tried an idea from a forum, which said I should run it as either pipewire or pulseaudio with -d as daemon (here) . Afterward, my system crashed. KDE is gone and I cannot reinstall it. Gnome cannot be installed either. How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.
Running startx results in an error but not in the terminal. It states something is wrong, which the system can't fix
The error of kde: libkf5configqml5 is depend on libkf5config-data... it also says libkf6screen-bin: libkf5screen-bin is broken. Plasma-workspace depends on libkuserfeedbackcore1, which can not be installed and many more errors.
I have Linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS tty4 (Tuxedo OS), with Kernel 6.5.0-10036-tuxedo

After trying various solutions like sudo apt-get autoremove, --ignore-depends, and sudo apt --fix-broken install and more without success.
I finally resolved the issue by booting Tuxedo OS from a USB. I downloaded an ISO from the Tuxedo Website and used Universal USB Installer to create a working ISO. Surprisingly, other software like Balena Etcher,  Rufus, or LiLi did not make a functional live image.
Once I had a bootable USB, I used the live image to transfer any remaining data and then booted the OS.
